# Assigning the text label from a UIButton to a UILabel not working

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uibutton, uilabel

I have this declared in the .h

```
IBOutlet UILabel *display;
```

and in the .m I am doing the following but its not working , keep saying that displat.text is null. Puzzled, help! Yes I am a noob.

```
NSLog(@"operation button pressed %@ is of class %@",[[sender titleLabel] text],[[[sender titleLabel] text] class] ); 
NSString *operation = [[sender titleLabel] text];
[display setText:operation];
NSLog(@"display text is of class %@ and equals %@",[display.text class], [display text]);
```

I also tried like this:

```
NSLog(@"digit button pressed %@ is of class %@",[sender currentTitle],[[sender currentTitle] class] );
display.text = (NSString *)[[sender titleLabel] text];
NSLog(@"display text is of class %@ and equals %@",[display.text class], [display text]);
```

Comment: You have NSLog() statements sprinkled here and there so ... what is the output in your run log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to check:

1. Make sure your "display" outlet is connected in Interface Builder.
2. Make sure your interface is fully loaded before calling this code.

Regarding item 2, it's easier to give you advice if you let us know where this problem code is being called from (from what method). Is it an action or at startup? Where?

Comment: its an action. I have calculator buttons (operations and digits) as IBActions and display as an IBOoutlet. I am trying to read the label from the button and assign it to the display.text to show it.

Comment: Okay ... so are the outlets connected? What's the output of the log statements? We can't help you if you don't post sufficient information.

Comment: Got it! you did help me. I had a mess between the UILabel and it not being connected right! Works now!!! Thanks!

Comment: Always check your outlets first. They're usually the first thing you forget. :-)